# Cygwin packages for creating and running Shell scripts in windows

Tags: windows, cygwin

I just started studying Unix shell scripting. I use a Windows XP. Just want to know which all Cygwin packages I need to install to run the bash scripts and commands in Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The packages included in the (default) Base installation should be enough for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Vixies Cron, will get you started with a linux like crontab for windows. Also cygstart will launch applications very well. Also make sure you install *collection of* type things from the cygwin setup.